# How to send just a string with http Post on Android?

Tags: android

i need to send a string to a server, but the only way i know to is by using namevaluepairs, but that sends the key and a value i just want to send one string, how do i do that?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:1455/Android/Android.svc/GetCompanyBusinessAreas");


                        try 
                        {           
                         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", companhiaIdS));




                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                         Log.i("Enviando:", nameValuePairs.toString());


                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            Log.i("Resposta:", response.getEntity().toString());
                            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

what can i use instead of namevaluepairs, because it send a list and the server is excpecting just one string?

Answer (score 1):

```
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("your string"));
```

Comment: thanks :) i couldnt find it anywhere because everybody uses namevaluepairs

Comment: its no working..and everywhere i go they say that you cant send a just a string or an int by http, you have to send a list or something...can you help me?